# Making SSDT just generate a SQL script (and not deploy a database)

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-data-tools

Having recently upgraded to SSDT 2012 I seem to be missing the option to just generate a T-SQL script instead of deploying the database to a server somewhere.

To be more accurate the predecessor to SSDT used to set the Deploy action to 'Generate script', but I cannot locate that option anywhere in the new version.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To generate a script from an offline data project in SSDT rather than deploy to a target database, configure the project settings as shown below

[image: SSDT deployment configuration dialogue boxes]

Comment: Thanks Lynn, have made this change and if it doesn't create the database over the next few days I'll change the accepted answer

Comment: @Lynn The link to the image is broken, do you know the name of the settings I need to change (and their values)?

Comment: @Lynn The link is not broken, the site on which the image is hosted was blocked by our company firewall :-( Sorry about that

Answer (score 7):

You may want to look at the SQLPackage command line. You can set the options there to use an action of "script" and specify an outputfile name to generate scripts instead of publishing the database. You can also do that through a batch file so it will generate a script every time. You still need to provide a source project and target database, though. The reference for SQLPackage can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=VS.103%29.aspx

Comment: Great alternate answer: CLI instead of GUI.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.

Is you select *Build > Publish ProjectName...*  from the menu bar, a dialog window pops-up with publishing options – there's a *Generate Script* button at the bottom of the dialog window.

Comment: And when I do this then it does it for each subsequent build until such time as I change it again?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I'll have to do it everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem where the SSDT project would attempt to deploy changes when the project was run.

In the project properties, choose the "Debug" tab.  Change the Start Action to "None". That will prevent it from trying to deploy at that time.